# what is difference between @EJB and @Resource? in dependency injection in EJB

Tags: annotations, ejb

I like to know what is the main difference between EJB @EJB and @Resource annotation? In which case we have to go for @EJB and @resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specification states, regarding @EJB:

> The Bean Provider uses the EJB annotation to annotate a ﬁeld or setter
>   property method of the bean class as a target for the injection of an
>   EJB reference. The reference may be to a session bean’s business
>   interface or to the local home interface or remote home interface of a
>   session bean or entity bean.

regarding @Resource(section 16.2.2):

> A field or method of a bean class may be annotated to request that an
>   entry from the bean’s environment be injected. Any of the types of
>   resources or other environment entries described in this chapter may
>   be injected.

Mentioned entries include: EJB reference, web service reference, resource manager connection factory reference, message destination reference, unit reference, persistence context reference, UserTransaction, CORBA ORB object, TimerService, EJBContext object

Comment: Copy information from documentation doesn`t help at all