# JavaEE @EJB vs @Resource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I would have a question concerning JavaEE Beans. 
I have developed a long time with Spring and Hibernate and now I change to JavaEE - so therefore sorry if it is a very simple question but currently I have no idea how to handle my problem.

I have two Beans which are registered in JNDI (on JBoss - see above). - that is ok so far. If I use @EJB as dependency injection in my Servlet than it works fine:

```
@EJB(name = "jndi/TestClassBean")
public TestClass testClass;
@EJB(name = "jndi/OtherBean")
public OtherBean otherBean;
```

If I change @EJB with @Resource, than I get a NullPointerException:

```
@Resource(name = "jndi/TestClassBean")
public TestClass testClass;
@Resource(name = "jndi/OtherBean")
public OtherBean otherBean;
```

Does enyone know what to do in order to get it done with @Resource? 
I have nothing declared in deplyment descriptior - is it mandatory for @Resource to declare it in DD?
Thanks!

> 16:39:51,482 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-7) JNDI bindings for session bean named OtherBean in deployment unit deployment ...

```
java:global/salzburgag-javaeetest-frontend/OtherBean!at.maxqu.test.OtherBeanLocal
java:app/...-javaeetest-frontend/OtherBean!at.maxqu.test.OtherBeanLocal
java:module/OtherBean!at.....test.OtherBeanLocal
java:global/...-javaeetest-frontend/OtherBean!at.....test.OtherBean
java:app/...-javaeetest-frontend/OtherBean!at.....test.OtherBean
java:module/OtherBean!at.maxqu.test.OtherBean
```

16:39:51,490 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-7) JNDI bindings for session bean named TestClassBean in deployment unit deployment ...

```
java:global/...-javaeetest-frontend/TestClassBean!at.....javaeesimpletest.TestClass
java:app/...-javaeetest-frontend/TestClassBean!at.....javaeesimpletest.TestClass
java:module/TestClassBean!at.maxqu.javaeesimpletest.TestClass
java:global/...-javaeetest-frontend/TestClassBean!at.....javaeesimpletest.TestClassBean
java:app/...-javaeetest-frontend/TestClassBean!at.....javaeesimpletest.TestClassBean
java:module/TestClassBean!at.....javaeesimpletest.TestClassBean
```

16:39:52,272 INFORMATION [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MS

Comment: Please refer the below link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900908/what-is-difference-between-ejb-and-resource-in-dependency-injection-in-ejb][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900908/what-is-difference-between-ejb-and-resource-in-dependency-injection-in-ejb

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `lookup`:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:global/...-javaeetest-frontend/TestClassBean!at.....javaeesimpletest.TestClass")
public TestClass testClass;

@Resource(lookup = "java:global/salzburgag-javaeetest-frontend/OtherBean!at.maxqu.test.OtherBeanLocal")
public OtherBean otherBean;
```